# Reverse the Endianness of a C structure

Tags: c, endianness

I have a structure in C that looks like this:

```
typedef u_int8_t NN;
typedef u_int8_t X;
typedef int16_t S;
typedef u_int16_t U;
typedef char C;

typedef struct{
 X test;
 NN test2[2];
 C test3[4];
 U test4;
} Test;
```

I have declared the structure and written values to the fields as follows:

```
Test t;
int t_buflen = sizeof(t);
memset( &t, 0, t_buflen);
t.test = 0xde;
t.test2[0]=0xad; t.test2[1]=0x00;
t.test3[0]=0xbe; t.test3[1]=0xef; t.test3[2]=0x00; t.test3[3]=0xde;
t.test4=0xdeca;
```

I am sending this structure via UDP to a server. At present this works fine when I test locally, however I now need to send this structure from my `little-endian` machine to a `big-endian` machine. I'm not really sure how to do this.

I've looked into using `htons` but I'm not sure if that's applicable in this situation as it seem to only be defined for `unsigned ints` of 16 or 32 bits, if I understood correctly.

Comment: given viraptor's response (below) addresses the approach, but you still need the mechanics, here is a good post on structs and endian issues... ***[here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/859535/645128)***.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think there may be two issues here depending on how you're sending this data over TCP.

### Issue 1: Endianness

As, you've said endianness is an issue. You're right when you mention using `htons` and `ntohs` for shorts. You may also find `htonl` and its opposite useful too.

Endianness has to do with the byte ordering of multiple-byte data types in memory. Therefore, for single byte-width data types you do not have to worry. In your case is is the 2-byte data that I guess you're questioning.

To use these functions you will need to do something like the following...

```
Sender:
-------
t.test     = 0xde; // Does not need to be swapped
t.test2[0] = 0xad; ... // Does not need to be swapped
t.test3[0] = 0xbe; ... // Does not need to be swapped
t.test4    = htons(0xdeca); // Needs to be swapped 

...

sendto(..., &t, ...);


Receiver:
---------
recvfrom(..., &t, ...);
t.test4    = ntohs(0xdeca); // Needs to be swapped
```

Using `htons()` and `ntohs()` use the Ethernet byte ordering... big endian. Therefore  your little-endian machine byte swaps `t.test4` and on receipt the big-endian machine just uses that value read (`ntohs()` is a noop effectively).

The following diagram will make this more clear...
[image: Endian swapping]

If you did not want to use the `htons()` function and its variants then you could just define the buffer format at the byte level. This diagram make's this more clear...
[image: Define byte format of buffer]

In this case your code might look something like

```
Sender:
-------
uint8_t buffer[SOME SIZE];
t.test     = 0xde;
t.test2[0] = 0xad; ... 
t.test3[0] = 0xbe; ... 
t.test4    = 0xdeca;

buffer[0] = t.test;
buffer[1] = t.test2[0];
/// and so on, until...
buffer[7] = t.test4 & 0xff;
buffer[8] = (t.test4 >> 8) & 0xff;    

...

sendto(..., buffer, ...);

Receiver:
---------
uint8_t buffer[SOME SIZE];
recvfrom(..., buffer, ...);

t.test     = buffer[0];
t.test2[0] = buffer[1];
// and so on, until...
t.test4    = buffer[7] | (buffer[8] << 8);
```

The send and receive code will work regardless of the respective endianness of the sender and receiver because the byte-layout of the buffer is defined and known by the program running on both machines.

However, if you're sending your structure through the socket in this way you should also note the caveat below...

### Issue 2: Data alignment

The article [***"Data alignment: Straighten up and fly right"***](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/pa-dalign/) is a great read for this one...

The other problem you might have is data alignment. This is not always the case, even between machines that use different endian conventions, but is nevertheless something to watch out for...

```
struct
{
    uint8_t  v1;
    uint16_t v2; 
}
```

In the above bit of code the offset of `v2` from the start of the structure could be 1 byte, 2 bytes, 4 bytes (or just about anything). The compiler cannot re-order members in your structure, but it can pad the distance between variables.

Lets say machine 1 has a 16-bit wide data bus. If we took the structure without padding the machine will have to do two fetches to get `v2`. Why? Because we access 2 bytes of memory at a time at the h/w level. Therefore the compiler could pad out the structure like so

```
struct
{
    uint8_t  v1;
    uint8_t  invisible_padding_created_by_compiler;
    uint16_t v2; 
}
```

If the sender and receiver differ on how they pack data into a structure then just sending the structure as a binary blob will cause you problems. In this case you may have to pack the variables into a byte stream/buffer manually before sending. This is often the safest way.

Comment: To deal with the alignment issue, most compilers also have some mechanism for specifying alignment, and in particular for specifying _packed_ alignment (ie, no padding). This could have some minor/subtle ramifications on performance, but I wouldn't worry about that too much.

Comment: @SchighSchagh: Yes this is a good point +1! Note that this can introduce portability issues however...

Comment: Thank you for a very detailed and clear answer. I was unclear as to whether the actual order of the bits in the byte had to be swapped, or just the bytes, thanks for clearing that up. As for the data alignment issue you pointed out, this was something I came across earlier in the development of the code and was able to get around using `#pragma pack(1)`

Comment: Glad to help. Thankfully it is only the bytes... on both BE and LE the bit order within the byte is the same.

Answer (score 4):

There's no endianness of the structure really. It's all the separate fields that need to be converted to big-endian when needed. You can either make a copy of the structure and rewrite each field using `hton`/`htons`, then send the result. 8-bit fields don't need any modification of course.

In case of TCP you could also just send each part separately and count on nagle algorithm to merge all parts into a single packet, but with UDP you need to prepare everything up front.

Answer (score 1):

The data you are sending over the network should be the same regardless of the endianess of the machines involved. The key word you need to research is **serialization**. This means converting a data structure to a series of bits/bytes to be sent over a network or saved to disk, which will always be the same regardless of anything like architecture or compiler.