# char[] to uint64_t

Tags: c, binary, char

I'm trying to convert an array of `char` into a `uint64_t` but it doesn't work.
Here's my code :

```
char input[8];
//Initialisation of input
int i,j;
uint64_t paquet=0;
for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        paquet+= (input[i] >> j) & 0x01;
        paquet = paquet << 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would make more sense to start with an array of `unsigned char`.

Comment: Do you have a spec? Endian issues? How do you want this conversion to proceed? What if `sizeof(uint64_t) != 8`?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the `input` buffer has stored the data in a little [***endian***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961420/reverse-the-endianness-of-a-c-structure/18962229#18962229) representation, which means that the least significant byte is at the lowest address and the most significant byte at the highest address then you can do something like the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int i;
    unsigned char input[8] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x5, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08 };
    uint64_t paquet = 0;
    for( i = 7; i >= 0; --i )
    {
        paquet <<= 8;
        paquet |= (uint64_t)input[i];
    }

    printf("0x%" PRIx64 "\n", paquet);

    return 0;
}
```

You can see the working example on [***ideone***](http://ideone.com/B1YnEH).

If the buffer is stored in big endian mode then reverse the loop.

Thank you to [***m24p***](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3259020/m24p) for pointing out a bug in my initial draft.

Comment: This is almost right.  You probably just want a single loop like this one.  Just trying to follow the two-loop logic made my head hurt.  That would not have been readable, maintainable code.  This is very close to right.

It has a bug in that it shifts after the or.  It needs to do the shift before.  Otherwise you're always going to have the 8 least significant bits at 0, and lose the top 8 most significant bits.  :

Comment: Yep there's a bug... just verifying on ideone... fixed and thanks for pointing that out (+1)... quite embarrassed!

Comment: Minor: Suggest `PRIX64` to more easily match `paquet` to `input`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this ?

```
uint64_t paquet = input[0]<<(8*7) | input[1]<<(8*6)
                                  | input[2]<<(8*5)
                                  | input[3]<<(8*4)
                                  | input[4]<<(8*3)
                                  | input[5]<<(8*2)
                                  | input[6]<<(8*1)
                                  | input[7];
```

Comment: `input[0]` is type `char`.  Performing a shift on it will not result in anything larger than `int`.

Answer (score 2):

```
char input[8] = "\x01\x23\x45\x67\x89\xAB\xCD\xEF";
uint64_t paquet = *(uint64_t*)"\x1\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0";

if(paquet == 1){
    //reverse
    char *f=&input[0], *b=&input[7];
    while(f<b){
        char tmp = *f;
        *f++ = *b;
        *b-- = tmp;
    }
}
paquet = *(uint64_t*)input;//memcpy(&paquet, input, sizeof(input));
```

Comment: +1 Nice endian detection.  (note: `(uint64_t*)"\x1\x0...` and `*(uint64_t*)input` may fail due to alignment restrictions.